What is the history behind Berber ritual tattooing and its cultural significance?
I am trying to research the historical significance of the Berber practice of ritual tattooing, but I am struggling to find any detailed information. Specifically I would like to know about the origin of this practice, and why it took place i.e. the cultural significance. From my research my understanding is also that the tattooing took place when a person reaches a specific age which I feel would also be good to know about to fully understand the context.
If there's any specifics I've missed in my question please let me know and I can update the above.

You could start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_tattooing#Berbers and the references there.

Yes I have seen this but I was hoping to get more detailed information and from a more reliable source than wikipedia

That's why you follow the references and look at them.
